# Reading a line of a text file from a specific position in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, text, fstream

I would like to read a text file in C++ in following manner:

1. Ignore the entire first line as it is simply meant as an introduction.
2. Only read the following lines from a specific position.

That starting position for reading is a fixed one and remains the same for every line; however, the numbers after that may be of variable length. I need to save all of these numbers from line 2 to line n into an Array.
At the moment I can read a regular 2D Array with `getline`. 
How can I work around these things?

An example for a line I want to read could be:

Person1: 25 988.3 0.0023 7

Answer (score 0):

To set the file to a position, use `std::ifstream::seekg()`.

To set the file to the beginning of a line, you must read and count the line endings.  Many text files have variable length text lines.

Comment: May I ask how you would implement `seekg()`? At the moment I use a `while`-loop with `getline` to read an Array with numbers only.

Comment: On method is to read through the entire file using `std::getline`; but before you use `std::getline`, use `std::ifstream::tellg()` to get the file position of the text line.  Store the file position in `std::vector`.  This will allow you to retrieve the starting position of each line in the file.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I work around these things?

You can't, unless you can ensure that all of the data lines after the first line are all the same length.

If you can't ensure that, then all you can do is read through all of the preceding lines.

An alternative I have employed in the past is to generate an 'index' of line start positions in a secondary file in binary format (so that I CAN jump directly to the right place in that file), and use that to jump to the right place in the text file. Of course that means that you need to regenerate that index file every time you replace/amend the data file.